# I was implementing QuickSort via C and i am getting error in line 2 (error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '=' token)

Tags: c, quicksort

I was implementing QuickSort via C and i am getting error in line 2 (error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '=' token). I can't understand the problem and solution both pls help. I am A beginner?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxz1z.png)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: I also encourage you to indent the code in the right way

Comment: @TobiSh Your edit gives the wrong impression to new users that posting pictures of code text is OK and that other users will even do the details of getting the markdown right to make it visible. Please read the comment by Sourav. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Comment: @Yunnosch fair point. will revert it

Comment: @TobiSH Wow, honestly impressed and in a good way surprised by your reaction.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks! I take this compliment. This is not twitter and it is OK to make mistakes and fix them ;-). We are all friends and here to help aren't we?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the int k = n is illegal, n must be a constant default value.